# total with select and conditions and group by

Tags: sql

```
------------------------------------------
Id       | CaseId   | FeeType |     Cost |
-----------------------------------------
1017796  | 2697789  |      29 |       50  
1018167  | 2697789  |       1 |      150 
1019493  | 2697789  |      15 |       30
1017799  | 2697790  |      29 |       50 
1018168  | 2697790  |       1 |      150 
1019494  | 2697790  |      15 |       0
-----------------------------------------
```

I want the output as 
If contrators Fee is equal to 0 then the TotalFee should be 0 and not the total of
AdminFee+SubFee+ContFee

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
CaseId   | AdminFee  | SubFee  | ContFee | TotalAdmin | TotalFee
------------------------------------------------------------------
2697789  |       50  |    150  |     30  |     200    |  230
------------------------------------------------------------------
2697790  |       50  |    150  |     0   |     200    |    0
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
@" select distinct a.CaseID 
  , sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 29 THEN b.Cost END) AS AdminFee
  , sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 1 THEN b.Cost END) AS SubFee
  , sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 15 THEN b.Cost END) AS ContFee
  ,sum (case when b.FeeType IN (1, 29) then b.Cost END) as TotalAdmin

From Fee a
GROUP BY a.CaseId
```

How do I modify the above select statement in order to get the total as 0 if there is no Contractor Fee
and if there is a contractorFee then the TotalFee = AdminFee+SubFee+ContFee

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well, you can use ISNULL or COALESCE statement:

ISNULL(field, value if null) -

```
 ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN b.FeeType = 15 THEN b.Cost END) AS ContFee)
```

or use CASE AND ISNULL:

```
 CASE
   IF b.FeeType != null THEN b.Cost
   ELSE 0
 END AS ContFee
```

Comment: I am calculating the totalFee which is 0 if the ContFee=0 if ContFee= a value  example ContFee=40 then the totalFee have a value which is AdminFee+SubFee+ContFee

Comment: CASE WHEN ContFee <> 0 THEN AdminFee+SubFee+ContFee ELSE 0 END

Comment: No, that does not seems to work as AdminFee, SubFee and ContFee are stored in the db as FeeType 1, 15, 29 and the cost for these FeeTypes is Stored under Cost where AdminFee =50, SubFee=150 and ContFee changes depending on what the contractor charges some times there is no ContFee that's the time we don't want to calculate the TotalAmt